# C++ CreateProcess ожидание ввода в CMD

Tags: c++, cmd

Всем привет! Существует ли способ (через CreateProcess или параметр в CMD) не Запускать программы которые требуют последующего ввода данных?

Т.е команда **dir** сразу выводит результат в консоль (я могу получить вывод через CreateProcess), но команда **ftp** запускает ftp.exe и консоль ждет пока я не объясню ftp что ему делать (**ftp>**) в связи с чем CreateProcess "виснет" (не возвращает output и ждет). Так вот, как мне предотвратить подобное? Может быть есть какой то ключ/параметр при запуске cmd или при вводе команды который запрещает ожидание ввода. В общем, рассчитываю на ваши советы.

P.S Чую что сейчас польются советы в стиле "просто не запускай программы вроде ftp", "юзай ftp -s:config" и т.д. Не надо так.

Comment: можно запустить программу, которая будет выполнять бесконечный цикл и тоже подвесит вам createprocess, без input'а. как вы вообще представляете себе проверку программы, которая может делать все что угодно? Не надо так.

Comment: @Kenpachi, а что должно происходить если такая команда (требующая ввода) запущена?

Попробуйте поконкретней сформулировать свой вопрос.

Comment: @avp, ничего не должно происходить, просто программа не должна виснуть при запуске программ как ftp.

@Yura Ivanov, а зачем проверять программу? Мб можно проверить что в ответе получил CreateProcess и получил ли он хоть что-то вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположу, что необходимо запускать непосредственно FTP.exe  в CreateProcess и передавать параметры командной строки, а не запускать CMD потом через него FTP 
Прокомментировать не могу вот и написал в виде ответа.

Comment: Да ftp.exe был просто для примера... в cmd может послаться что угодно, dir, copy, explorer.exe, не суть.

Comment: теперь вообще не понятно зачем тогда это всё.
запустите вы explorer.exe, что ожидаем получить из консоли?
я подумал, что вы типа надстройки хотите сделать над ftp или cmd что просто выбрал команду в ваше программе вбил что для ее работы нужно и отправил, в ответ получил результат.
опишите конкретнее что хотите я думаю тут большинство просто не может понять что в о концовке нужно то

Comment: Дак я же написал, необходимо чтоб те команды, что сразу выполняются и выводят output (такие как dir) выполнялись как всегда, а команды подобные ftp, т.е те что ждут ввода от пользователя не выполнялись (сделать, как бы, предохранитель). Вот и все. И да, это надстройка над cmd.

Как вариант использовать "&" в конце каждой команды, но тогда вывода не будет в любом случае.

Comment: @Kenpachi, вообще-то я с виндой не дружу и не уверен, что до конца понял, **чего именно** Вы хотите, но попробовал в окошке с командной строкой (Вы ведь в окошке команду запускаете?) такие штуки:


    echo | dir

вроде нормально выводит

и

    echo | ftp

пишет "Недопустимая команда." и завершается.

Может это Вам как-то поможет.

Comment: @avp не знаю, как это будет в win32api, а в unixlike'ах создать пару труб (для stdin/stdout), запустить процесс, и если он чего-то захочет читать (select?) -- прибить его, чтоб не мучался

Comment: @avp, дурное дело не хитрое:

    echo | copy con test.txt
    echo | start /w ftp
    echo | msg * /w /time:0 "hang it to death"

Comment: @alexlz, в них я бы просто сделал 

    dup2(open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY), 0);

перед exec-ом.

Просто решил не грузить ТС-а. Он же все равно в \*nix-ы уже не пойдет.

Comment: @alexlz, в win32 так тоже можно, естественно. Но, во-первых, не все программы могут просить что-то из stdin (см. мой третий пример чуть выше), во-вторых, бывает, что и вывод не заканчивается (ping 8.8.8.8 -t) или идет довольно долго (netstat -a). Что считать подвисшей программой не понятно.

Comment: @avp Если у дочернего процесса странная реакция на EOF, то такой вариант не подойдёт

@Yura Ivanov

    Всем привет! Существует ли способ (через CreateProcess или параметр в CMD) не Запускать программы которые требуют последующего ввода данных?

Comment: @avp, спасибо, вроде то что надо.

@Yura Ivanov, про pipe для stdin хорошая идея, только как проверить ждет ли процесс этот самый stdin.

Comment: @alexlz, ...в связи с чем CreateProcess "виснет". Причина зависания - ожидание ввода, одна из многих, примеры я привел. То, что вы предложили прибивать только программы, ожидающие ввода, не решит других вопросов. В этом суть моих комментариев.  
@Kenpachi, про пайпы можете начать, например, отсюда http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351/ru

Comment: не знал такой особенности труб))(pipes)
спс